# Why do compiler gives error instead of warning for variable which is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I know there are lot of question which is asked previously about

> The variable which is assigned but its value is never used

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658839/variable-is-assigned-but-its-value-is-never-used-c),[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330491/weird-warning-is-assigned-but-its-value-is-never-used) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324313/c-sharp-warning-the-variable-is-assigned-but-its-value-is-never-used)

I am getting compile time Error instead of warning which causes compile or rebuild to fail.
i didn't update my Visual studio 2015 nor do i installed any VS extension

so my question is what can i do so Visual studio show `warning` instead of Compile time Error.

[image]

Comment: i would leave this on any time.

Comment: Actually you get a compiler-error, not an exception. An exception is something thrown at *runtime*. Anyway good question.

Comment: Thanks i will edit my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the project-properties is a setting "Treat warnings as errors" which you apparently switched on.

[image: project-properties]

To undo: Project->Properties->Build->Treat warnings as errors->None

(`None` is the default-setting for new projects.)

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warnaserror-compiler-option) for reference.

**Note:**

It's certainly still a good idea to set this setting to `All`, to ensure the code is error- and "garbage"-free.

Comment: Comment: why to undo? Please add a humble hint to fix the code, not to silence the compiler.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why should i? The question is about what to do to show a warning instead of an error. Not how to fix the code.

Comment: And which is a bad practice. Remember, this question and answer is not only for the OP but visible to all. Thats the actual scope of any info here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is your opinion. The default-setting is `None`. From this i conclude that MS considers this not as "bad practice". I would rather say, it is a bad practice to publish software with compiler warnings. But i will  add a hint in my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

To treat all compiler warnings as compilation errors:

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project
   menu, click Properties.
2. Click the Compile tab.
3. Select the Treat all warnings as errors check box. (or select the
   build setting and change the “treat warnings as errors” settings to
   TRUE)

To disable all compiler warnings

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu click Properties.
2. Click the Compile tab.
3. Select the Disable all warnings check box. (or select the build setting and change the “treat warnings as errors” settings to FALSE.)